# Is it possible to download an audio file and play it using React Native Expo?

Tags: authentication, react-native, api-design, fetch-api, expo

I have audio files hosted on a server that I'd like my app to access after authenticating. Users send a GET request which includes an authentication token, and the server returns the binary audio data.

As far as I can see there is no way to save this 'blob' as an audio file to the filesystem. The current implementation of fetch in react-native doesn't support blobs: [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/11417)

... and the ideally-suited react-native-fetch-blob library isn't supported in expo either: [link](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/123)

Additionally I can see no way of streaming the audio file from the server. The included [audio library with expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v19.0.0/sdk/audio.html) allows streaming of audio from a url (e.g. http://example.com/myaudio.mp3) however I can't see any way to attach an authorisation header to the request (e.g. "Authorization": "Bearer [my-token]").

Is there a way of achieving this, either by downloading and saving the audio blob, or streaming from a url with an authorisation header included in the request? I could detach my project from Expo but I'd like to leave that as a last-resort.

Comment: If you mean Load sound from the network, Check This Module: (https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound)

Comment: I opened an issue on the Expo repo about the Authorization header: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/425

Comment: Also, the blob support PR you link just landed today, but I'm not sure exactly when it'll be on the stable release of React Native. Could be a month or two.

Comment: @SedricHeidarizarei I don't think that will work within Expo without detaching.

Comment: @dikaiosune Thanks for opening the issue. I'd considered fetching the audio in base 64 encoding workaround referenced by this issue: [github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/11417](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/11417) but also no way to input that into Expo's audio functions that I could see. Ideally I'd like the ability to cache the audio client-side to prevent repeated calls to the server.

Comment: @Tom did you ever find a solution for caching audio content?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is. You need to use the [Audio](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/audio.html) module exposed by expo to do it. Below are the steps that you have to follow to load and play an audio file from a given URL. I've also copied over the code for my component that is doing the same for me.

- Load Audio module exposed by expo

  > `import { Audio } from 'expo'`
- Create a new sound Object from it

  > `soundObject = new Audio.Sound()`
- Asynchronously load your file

  > `await this.soundObject.loadAsync({ uri: this.props.source })`
- Once loaded play the loaded file using

  > `this.soundObject.playAsync()`

Below is a simple component that I wrote for doing it -

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableNativeFeedback } from 'react-native';
import { Audio } from 'expo';

class AudioPlayer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isPlaying: false };

    this.loadAudio = this.loadAudio.bind(this);
    this.toggleAudioPlayback = this.toggleAudioPlayback.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadAudio();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.soundObject.stopAsync();
  }

  async loadAudio() {
    this.soundObject = new Audio.Sound();
    try {
      await this.soundObject.loadAsync({ uri: this.props.source /* url for your audio file */ });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('ERROR Loading Audio', e);
    }
  }

  toggleAudioPlayback() {
    this.setState({
      isPlaying: !this.state.isPlaying,
    }, () => (this.state.isPlaying
      ? this.soundObject.playAsync()
      : this.soundObject.stopAsync()));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={this.toggleAudioPlayback}>
        <View style={this.props.style}>
          {this.props.children}
        </View>
      </TouchableNativeFeedback>
    );
  }
}

export default AudioPlayer;
```

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out. I should've load the sound in componentdidmount using async. In case someone met this problem

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.loadAudio();

   }

//async function to load the audio
async loadAudio() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const id = navigation.getParam("id");
    this.sound = new Audio.Sound();
    for (let i = 0; i < soundArray.length; i++) {
      if (soundArray[i].id === id) {
        this.currentSound = soundArray[i];
        console.log(this.currentSound);

        break;
      }
    }
    try {
      await this.sound.loadAsync({
        uri: this.currentSound.sound /* url for your audio file */
      });
      await this.sound.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(
        this._updateScreenForSoundStatus
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("ERROR Loading Audio", e);
    }
  }
```